# Inequality regarding sum and division

Tags: inequality, summation

I need your expertise in solving the following:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a,c \geq 0$ and $b,d > 0$.
Find a $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that:
$$ \frac{a+c}{b+d} \geq y \cdot \left ( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \right) $$

Note that $y$ should work for any $a,b,c,d$ which comply to the inequalities above!

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Take $c=0$ and you see that $$\frac{a}{b+d}\geq y\cdot \frac{a}{b}$$Since $b,d>0$ it follows that for any $y>0$, we can always find a pair of $(a,b,d)$ such that the inequality doesn't hold. For example, if $y \geq 1$, we can take $(a,b,d) = (1,1,1)$, and if $y<1$, we can take $(a,b,d) = (1,1,\frac{2-2y}{y})$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
How would I establish a lower bound for $ \frac{a + c}{b + d}$ ?

Comment: Hi, it isn't necessary to specifically establish a lower bound. Rather, we notice that when $y=0$ the inequality always holds, while for any $y>0$ there exists situations where the inequality doesn't hold, concluding that $y=0$.

Comment: Nice approach, but $0$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{R^+}$, possibly it has no correct answer.

Comment: Yes, good point :)

Comment: what if $a,b,c,d > 0$ ? what happens then?